# how to use find on a map of int,string

Tags: c++, dictionary

This is probably easy but i've been awake for too long.

So I have a map< int, string> and i'm trying to use the function find

```
iter=mapInKey.find(int)->second;
if (iter != mapInKey.end() )
{
    outFileTxt << iter;
}
```

But I get this error: `no matching function for call to std::map<int, std::basic_string<char> >::find(std::string&)`

All I want to do is output the other pair value of int

Comment: Argument of find can not be int, and you can not use second.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
    std::map <int,std::string>::iterator it = mapInKey.find( val ); //val is the integer key you search for

    if(it != mapInKey.end()){
     // do something 
     cout<< it->second; // this will print the string
   }
```

**Edit**

I think you want to search by string. then you are declaring the map wrong. Use this

```
map<string,int> m;
m["Hi"]= 1;
m["Hello"]= 2;
map<string,int>::iterator it = m.find("Hello");
if(it != m.end())
{
  cout<< it->first<<":"<<it->second<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error. is my map declaration wrong std::map <int,std::string> mapInKey;

Comment: you are passing the `string` in `find` method. but you should pass 'int', as 'int' is the key, `string` is the value. to search using `string` the map should be declared as `std::map<string,int> mapInKey`